# Run Powershell with arguments via CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have the following .BAT script that basically calls Powershell and it works fine.

```
CMD /C PowerShell "SL -PSPath '%CD%'; $Path = (GL).Path; SL ~; Start PowerShell -Verb RunAs -Args \"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass" SL -PSPath '"$Path"'; & '".\RDPSwitchToConsle.ps1"'"\""
```

I'm trying to extend it to add more arguments, specifically `-WindowStyle Hidden`.

I've tried a couple of things, but can't get the script .BAT to run. It just opens Powershell straight away and closes immediately, which is a sign that the arguments/parameters are not loaded correctly due to incorrect structure.

I've tried adding the argument like this:

```
CMD /C PowerShell "SL -PSPath '%CD%'; $Path = (GL).Path; SL ~; Start PowerShell -Verb RunAs -Args \"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -WindowStyle Hidden" SL -PSPath '"$Path"'; & '".\RDPSwitchToConsle.ps1"'"\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `-WindowStyle Hidden` to the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) (`start`) call, not to the nested `powershell.exe` call.

Here's a simplified version of your command:

```
PowerShell "SL ~; Start -WindowStyle Hidden -Verb RunAs PowerShell \"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass SL -PSPath '%CD%'; ^& .\RDPSwitchToConsle.ps1\""
```